# integral of a sin function with arbitrary argument

Tags: calculus

For grins, I'm making a symbolic math engine.

As part of this, I typed the following into WolframAlpha:

```
integral(sin(f(x)))dx
```

and it returned

```
(no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions)
```

So I tried to see if I could derive an answer.

The following was my approach:

Starting with the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}(cos(f(x))) = (\frac{d}{dx}(-f(x)))*sin(f(x))$
$$\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(cos(f(x)))}{\frac{d}{dx}(-f(x))} = sin(f(x))$$
$$\int\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(cos(f(x)))}{\frac{d}{dx}(-f(x))} dx = \int sin(f(x)) dx$$
$$\int(\frac{d}{dx}(cos(f(x))))(\frac{d}{dx}(-f(x)))^{-1} dx = \int sin(f(x)) dx$$
Then, using integration by parts in the form
$$\int u' * v dx = u*v - \int u*v' dx$$
I arrived at
$$\frac{cos(f(x))}{-f'(x)} - \int cos(f(x))*\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} dx = \int sin(f(x)) dx$$

I checked it against f(x) = x
$$\frac{cos(x)}{-1} - \int cos(x)*\frac{0}{1} dx = \int sin(x) dx$$
$$-cos(x) - \int 0 dx = \int sin(x) dx$$
$$-cos(x) - c = \int sin(x) dx$$
Yielding the correct answer.

So my question is, is my math wrong anywhere, and if not, is this a useful formula?

Clearly it only works if $f'(x) \neq 0$, but I suspect the cosine in the integral is problematic.

Comment: Your solution is not in terms of elementary functions; you just solved an integral using another integral. Parts integration is generally able to produce such expressions quite easily, most of which are relatively uninteresting.

Comment: Can you suggest a more interesting approach?

Comment: perhaps making more assumptions about $f(x)$? I'm not familiar with any theory in which $\int \sin(f(x))dx$ has a distinguished role however. That certainly doesn't mean it doesn't exist, just that I haven't heard of it.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, my ultimate goal is a program which evaluates math expressions symbolically.  Elementary functions and derivatives were trivial to implement; I knew integrals are significantly harder (and a still-unsolved problem in that field, I believe).